# How can one add the dotcover exclude file settings to the TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, dotcover

I'm trying to add the "exclude file" settings (for jetbrains-dotcover) that I make to the TFS in order to 
avoid co programmers having to set the same settings manually.

After trying around and searching I didn't find any info there and thus my question is:
Is this possible to do? And if so how?

Comment: How are you running doTCover in TFS?  You will need to describe what you are doing in greater detail in order to get a decent answer.

Comment: I'm not running it "on" the TFS. I'm storing the projects (aka the whole solution) in TFS. I'm running dotcover "normally" by right clicking on the Unit tests project and click "cover unit tests with DotCover". Then I have to include new files in the DAL project from the dotcover (dal isnt part of those tests). When I then check in into the TFS my co workers need to also exclude those projects or files themselves manually instead of having the same exclude settings as me there. And that is what we want to avoid: Everyone needing to do the same.   That what you meant there @a.vector ?

Comment: Yes that makes more sense.  I've expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am presuming that you are running dotCover from the command line in TFS.  With reference to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/webhelp/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html) on running DotCover from the command line you need to add a parameter to your call to exclude the assemblies:

/Filters=ARG                 : (Optional) Specify coverage filters using following syntax: +:module=*;class=*;function=*;
                                 Use -:myassembly to exclude an assembly from code coverage. Asterisk wildcard (*) is supported here

If you have a dotCover xml file for your coverage settings you can put the exclusion into it.  See the same [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/webhelp/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html) for editing the xml.  I imagine the bit you need to add would look something like this:

```
<Filters>
  <ExcludeFilters>
    <FilterEntry>
      <ModuleMask>AssemblyToExclude.dll</ModuleMask>
      <ModuleMask>*Tests*</ModuleMask> <!--This is an example to exclude all assemblies with Tests in their name-->
    </FilterEntry>
  </ExcludeFilters>
</Filters>
```

There is some general info in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/webhelp/Running_Coverage_Analysis_from_the_Command_LIne.html) on how to set up running from the command line.

*Proviso: I haven't tried what I have suggested, I am merely projecting from my own DotCover/TeamCIty TFS experience.  More information may provide a more accurate answer.

**Update:**
If you are using dotCover as per @Thomas comment, then you can edit the filters for you machine by running dotCover and selecting File=>Edit Coverage Filters...  If you add a filter there it will also apply to any coverage run from Visual Studio.  For example adding an assembly *Test* exclude filter will stop any assembly with the word Test in from being included in the reports:

[image: Coverage Filters]

I would think that your team would need to have the same exclusion filters setup on all their machines.

**Update2:**
I found where the per solution filter settings are stored.  They are in your DotSettings file next to your sln (e.g. MyProject.sln has MyProject.sln.DotSettings).  In order to get the exclusion into this file you should in Visual studio with your solution open go to DotCover->Edit Coverage Filters and Add a Filter for the current solution.

[image: Add solution Filter]

This yields the following info in your DotSettings file:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/FilterSettingsManager/CoverageFilterXml/@EntryValue">&lt;data&gt;&lt;IncludeFilters /&gt;&lt;ExcludeFilters&gt;&lt;Filter ModuleMask="*Maths*" ModuleVersionMask="*" ClassMask="*" FunctionMask="*" IsEnabled="True" /&gt;&lt;/ExcludeFilters&gt;&lt;/data&gt;</s:String>
```

If you commit the DotSettings file to TFS your team will get the exclusions.  See the docs about sharing your settings [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/webhelp/dotCover__Sharing_Coverage_Filters.html) and the docs and about setting them up [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/webhelp/dotCover__Setting_up_Coverage_Filters.html).

Comment: hmmm we are using it by clicking on the appropriate command to start dotcover so we aer not using the command line option there. 
I didnt see the .xml in the TFS does one have to manually include it for this to ave a chance to work? (thus that you can "deoploy" your exclude settings and not have them solely locally)?

Comment: @Thomas, I've updated the answer (again ;) ) to show how you can do this.